# dispatch is still expecting an Action even when redux-thunk installed?

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux-thunk

I'm trying to use redux-thunk in a TypeScript-based React Native project. My Actions are defined as

```js
export type Action<T> = {
  type: T,
  payload?: any
}
```

My store is defined as

```js
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import logger from 'src/redux/middleware/logger'
import rootReducer from 'src/redux/reducers'

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(logger, thunk))
export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

My action constructor is defined as

```js
export const setRepeat = (repeat: Repeating) => (
  dispatch: Dispatch<Action>,
  getState: () => AppState
) =>
  dispatch<Action>({
    payload: repeat,
    type: actionTypes.SET_REPEAT,
  })
```

`Repeating` is a simple enum:

```js
export enum Repeating {
  All = 'all',
  None = 'none',
  Single = 'single',
}
```

And when I attempt to dispatch this action with

```js
store.dispatch(setRepeat('all' as Repeating))
```

I get this error

```
TS2345: Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: Dispatch<Action<string>>, getState: () => AppState) => Action<string>' but required in type 'Action<string>'.
```

From what I can tell, this means that `setRepeat` is returning a function (which makes sense, that's what it's defined to do). But `store.dispatch` is not expecting a function like redux-thunk allows and is still expecting an `Action`.

I can't seem to find any explanation of why thunk isn't providing correct types here, or what I need to do to correct this problem.

- react-native: 0.57.7
- redux: 4.0.1
- react-redux: 6.0.0
- redux-thunk: 2.3.0

Comment: Can you provide the Repeating interface? I have an idea of what's wrong but need that code to confirm, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I added that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue has been brought up on github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/103)

To summarize, you need to add the types:

```
const store = createStore(
rootReducer,
applyMiddleware(
    thunk as ThunkMiddleware<IState, Actions>, // this is crucial
));
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW**

The problem here is that `dispatch` takes a type of `Action<T>` which has a property `type` but you are sending it a function, and functions don't have types. Notice that `setRepeat` is a function that returns another function.

```
store.dispatch(setRepeat('all' as Repeating)(dispatcherInstance,getStateFunction))
```

I would need to see more of your code but it seems you're going about this a little bit the wrong way.

Comment: Yes. redux-thunk adds a middleware so that action creators can return a function to do computations and then dispatch (or not) later. The problem is that `store.dispatch` doesn't seem to have a type signature that takes this change into consideration. My question is "Is that my fault or redux-thunk's fault, and either way, what can I do?"

Comment: You've typed Dispatch as type Action, but the dispatch instance that gets passed into your function `dispatcherInstance` is not of type Action. Thunk doesn't have that type here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js#L2 see this closed issue https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/103